# How to use densenet in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, anaconda

I notice densenet has been added to keras (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/applications)and I want to apply it in my project but when I tried to import it in jupyter anaconda, I got an error saying:

module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'densenet'

it seems like densenet has not been incorporated into current version of keras.

Any idea how can I add it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Densenet was added in keras version 2.1.3.  What version of keras are you running?

Have you tried to update keras with `pip install keras --upgrade` since January?

Comment: I am using keras 2.0.9 (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras). Am I able to update keras in anaconda?

Comment: It looks like the most recent version available on the anaconda website is 2.0.9.  You can get the latest version from the command line using pip.  If you haven't already; make a python 3.5 environment on your computer and then install keras there using this guide: https://keras.io/#installation

Comment: So by this you mean I cannot do it using anacoda but just pure python right?

Comment: You can use your anaconda installation to setup a python environment from the command line: `conda create -n python35 python=3.5` See https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html for more info on python environments.